# Response ZIP file by Django

Tags: python, django, zip

I try to download img from url, add it to zip archive and then response this archive by Django HttpResponse.

```
import os
import requests
import zipfile
from django.http import HttpResponse

url = 'http://some.link/img.jpg' 
file = requests.get(url)
data = file.content
rf = open('tmp/pic1.jpg', 'wb')
rf.write(data)
rf.close()
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('tmp/album.zip', 'w') # This file is ok
filename = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath('tmp/pic1.jpg'))
zipf.write('tmp/pic1.jpg', filename)
zipf.close()
resp = HttpResponse(open('tmp/album.zip', 'rb'))
resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=album.zip'
resp['Content-Type'] = 'application/zip'
return resp # Got corrupted zip file
```

When I save file to tmp folder - it's ok, I can extract it.
But when I response this file I get 'Error 1/2/21' on MacOS or Unexpected EOF if I try to open in Atom editor (just for test).
I also used StringIO instead of saving zip file, but it doesn't influence the result.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Python 3, you'd do it like this:

```
import os, io, zipfile, requests
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Get file
url = 'https://some.link/img.jpg'
response = requests.get(url)
# Get filename from url
filename = os.path.split(url)[1]
# Create zip
buffer = io.BytesIO()
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer, 'w')
zip_file.writestr(filename, response.content)
zip_file.close()
# Return zip
response = HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue())
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-zip-compressed'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=album.zip'

return response
```

That's without saving the file. Downloaded file goes directly to `io`.

To response saved file, use this syntax:

```
response = HttpResponse(open('path/to/file', 'rb').read())
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I've already used io to create the file. But the problem is with responsed file, not with a created one.

Comment: @E.Mozz: To return the file, add .read() to open(), `open('tmp/album.zip', 'rb').read())`.

Comment: It didn't change anything, still got an error when try to open an archive.

Comment: Simple and best solution. Thanks a lot.